# How to remove CSS Class with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tampermonkey

I am very new to CSS and javascript, so take it easy on me.

I am trying to remove the class `disable-stream` from each of the div elements under the div class="stream-notifications". (See image, below)

I have tried the following in Tampermonkey, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
disable-stream.classList.remove("disable-stream");})();
```

[image: screen shot of page structure]

Comment: Avoid images of texts - it is better to read if you paste the text properly formatted here.

Comment: Surprisingly, I couldn't find a good dupe target for this.  Good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks to be an AJAX-driven web page, so you need to use AJAX-aware techniques to deal with it. EG [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/2625891), or `MutationObserver`, or similar.

Here's **a complete script** that should work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remove a select class from nodes
// @match    *://app.hubspot.com/reports-dashboard/*
// @match    *://app.hubspot.com/sales-notifications-embedded/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.
console.log ("Do you see this?");

waitForKeyElements (".disable-stream", removeDSclass);

function removeDSclass (jNode) {
    console.log ("Cleaned node: ", jNode);
    jNode.removeClass ("disable-stream");
}
```

---

Note that there are two `@match` statements because the nodes, that the OP cared about, turned out to be in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks the answer. Trying this out now. 
This did not work either. I think the script is running too soon. The activity stream is one of the last things to load on the page. I wish I could share the link with you to try yourself, but it's behind my login wall.

Comment: Note that I am able to get the desired result if I manually remove the class from each `Div` in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: This kind of script never stops running.  Did you change the `@match` to whatever your page is?  Does Tampermonkey show this script running?  What shows on the console?

Comment: Load and run the new script, changing the `@match` to the actual site/path.   What do you see on the console?

Comment: Yes Tampermonckey shows the script is running as far as I can see. Nothing related to the script in the console that I can see.

Comment: I have changed the `@match` to the actual path. I will link to what I see in the console.

Comment: Use the latest version of the script that I just edited.

Comment: It shows those warnings even with the script disabled though.

Comment: Those warnings are page related.  Not script related.  Use the version of the script from about 40 seconds ago.

Comment: Ok, finally see the message in the console.

Comment: You should see more than 1 message.

Comment: It's printing to the console fine, but the classes are still there.

Comment: What, exactly, is printing to the console?

Comment: All I get is the `Do you see this?`

Comment: it worked! Thanks so much for your help and the chat!

Answer (score 2):

```
var divs =document.getElementsByClassName("stream-notifications");

divs=Array.from(divs);

divs.forEach(function(div){
  div.classList.remove('disable-stream');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this using jQuery

```
$(".disable-stream div").removeClass("disable-stream");
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hP4IyF64trUEjTmZpwBK?p=preview)